# Nested forms workaround

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm rather aware that nested forms are invalid, I am building a simple form with php and which needs to contain another form that controls an ajax image upload box so that i can feed the filepath into the original form.

example code below;

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input>
    </fieldset>
    <form action="js/ajaxupload.php" method="post" name="sleeker" id="sleeker" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="maxSize" value="9999999999" />
        <input type="hidden" name="maxW" value="400" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fullPath" value="http://192.168.10.10:8080/intranet/dashboard/uploads/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="relPath" value="../uploads/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="colorR" value="255" />
        <input type="hidden" name="colorG" value="255" />
        <input type="hidden" name="colorB" value="255" />
        <input type="hidden" name="maxH" value="200" />
        <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="filename" />
        <input type="file" name="filename" style="float:left; width:40% !important;" onchange="ajaxUpload(this.form,'js/ajaxupload.php?filename=name&amp;maxSize=9999999999&amp;maxW=200&amp;fullPath=http://192.168.10.10:8080/intranet/dashboard/uploads/&amp;relPath=../uploads/&amp;colorR=255&amp;colorG=255&amp;colorB=255&amp;maxH=300','upload_area','File Uploading Please Wait…&lt;br /&gt;&lt;img src=\'images/loader_light_blue.gif\' width=\'128\' height=\'15\' border=\'0\' /&gt;','&lt;img src=\'images/error.gif\' width=\'16\' height=\'16\' border=\'0\' /&gt; Error in Upload, check settings and path info in source code.'); return false;" />
    </form>
    <fieldset>
        <input>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input>
    </fieldset>
<submit>
</form>
```

In previous project's I have just placed the image upload below the original form and fed the hidden inputs back into the original form, unfortunately that won't be possible for this project,

any ideas to get around this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: if you are only using the controls for ajax, you don't need a form. controls can be outside forms

Comment: @einacio could you go into a little more detail, my ajax experience is entirely tweaking online examples so unsure which controls your referring too

Comment: Why can't you "[place] the image upload below the original form and [feed] the hidden inputs back into the original form"?

Comment: it's based on the layout of the page and the location of the upload box, I do not want to be moving things so extremely with css

Comment: controls: inputs, select, textarea, buttons

Comment: how would i submit those values if they were outside of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any system to parse the External_form.pl to Internal_form.pl. For example:

1. Form.html

   ```
   <html>
   ....
   ....
   <form ... method="post" action="External_form.pl">
   ....
   ....
   </form>
   ```

   This form post values to External_form.pl
2. External_form.pl

   It validates the Posted_Data and send this value again to Another Form Internal_Form.pl
3. Internal_Form.pl

   It finally sends the data to (External.pl or to the Form.html) and processed the validated date at the backend.

Comment: Are you posting an answer, or asking a question?  If an answer, please add details to your post so that the original questioner can make use of your information; if a question, please click the Ask Question button to post it as a question.